# Apktool version

Tags: linux, apk-tools

When I type apktool -version in the terminal, it tells me that it has version 2.6.0 When I type ./apktool -version in /usr/local/bin, it prints 2.7.0. How can I bring apktool to 2.7.0 version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two conflicting installations of `apktool`. Probably one from your distro, and one manually installed.

Uninstall the one you don't want — can't tell you how, because you've not told us what you distro is.